# reading new line char using java

Tags: java, line, newline

Help guys, i've just seen this example in the web. i would like to use this to print exactly the contents of a text file in the same format containing new lines, but it just prints out the first line. thanks

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

      public class Program
      {
          public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
          {
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("B:\\input.txt"));
          String str = scanner.nextLine(); 

          // Convert the above string to a char array.
          char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

          // Display the contents of the char array.
          System.out.println(arr);
          }
      }
```

Comment: You need a loop to read line-by-line.

Comment: Have a look at the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). The Scanner class has a hasNext() method, so you can loop as long as the scanner has another token to read, and read one line at a time using nextLine() within the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("B:\\input.txt"));
        String str;
        while ((str = scanner.nextLine()) != null)
            // No need to convert to char array before printing
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

The nextLine() method provides only one line, you must call it until have a null ( ~ C's EOF )

Answer (score 3):

Try this.. To read the whole file as it is.....

```
File f = new File("B:\\input.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(fr);

String s = null;

while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // Do whatever u want to do with the content of the file,eg print it on console using SysOut...etc
}

br.close();
```

**But still if you want to use Scanner then try this....**

```
while ( scan.hasNextLine() ) {
    str = scan.nextLine();
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
}
```

Comment: Even i wondered abt it, but as it was in the question i wrote it as it is..cause i have already incurred some burnt trying to correct the un-intentional mistakes.

Comment: Use `/` instead of `\\ `, so that it will work on every OS rather than working on Windows only.

Comment: Ya...thats a good tip.. Well i studied once "\\" for Network Path, "//" for Browser Path, "\" Folders, "/" for Webpages, "/" works in Linux, Cisco Devices..